# How to fix automatic changed DOM-Position of Form-Closing-Tag while onload by jQuery.get()

Tags: jquery, forms, post, parameters, is-empty

I started a coding project with datatransfer between Webbrowser and SQL-Database.

There´s a Mainpage that loads a second HTML-Document into a `<div id="DivID"></div>` by jQuery.get().
The second document contains
`<tr><form><td><input name="Test" value="Message">[...]</td></form></tr>`.

By opening the Web-Projekt, DOM-Code was changed autom. into
`<form></form><tr><td><input name="Test" value="Message">[...]</td></tr>` I´m using: (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0)

I already tried to locate the causer of this mysterium by using
`$.get('url', function(data) {$('#DivID').html(data); alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );});` The Alert shows correctly: `<tr><form><td><input name="Test" value="Message">[...]</td></form></tr>`.

I also tested to open the second HTML-Document and send Form. There´s no abnormality and it works fine.

Feel free to have a look to my webprojekt:
User: Stackover
Pass: Helpme

https://Stackover:Helpme@juh-technik.de/Bereitstellungsraum/V3.php?PIN=07119&Mode=Play

Is there somebody who knows reason of this `<form></form>` handling by browser DOM and is able to explain?

Comment: _"The Alert shows correctly..."_ - No, it doesn't. It shows a weird mix of markup, style definitions, meta tags and JavaScript - including invalid markup.

Comment: @Andreas: The alert shows at my screen in the way of <tr><form><td><input name="Test" value="Message"></td><script>[...]</script></form></tr>. Why you think it´s weird mix of markup?

Comment: Looks like you've removed at least the meta tags at the top. For the "weird mix" -> https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Element form not allowed as child of element table in this context.